# Convert Shell script to json

Tags: json

how do i save shell script output to a json file? I need to convert to json to be able to send to WooCommerce.

````
username=USER
passwd=PASS
dominio=DOMAIN

json=$(curl -s -X POST \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=modulo-retaguardaview" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=bd82bd01-e543-4531-bb53-794196595426" \
  --data-urlencode "username=${username}" \
  --data-urlencode "password=${passwd}" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
https://auth.cliente.com.br/auth/realms/GERA/protocol/openid-connect/token) \
&& token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"access_token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "Token gerado com sucesso!"


curl --location --request GET "https://${dominio}.cliente.com.br/pdvcore/api/v1/ecommerce/produtos" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"```
````